# How do I delete cached password for encrypted volume?

Tags: password, encryption

I am novice Ubuntu user.  For laughs I encrypted an external USB drive and put a punch of secret stuff on it.  It used to be that every-time I would attach the drive I would be challenged for a password.  At some point I inadvertently clicked "remember password" and now the volume mounts automagically.

How can I remove the cached password so I will be asked for a password each time I mount the volume?

Thanks!

Comment: How did you encrypt the flash drive? What tool/application?

Comment: I used the Disk Utility.  Removed the exFat partition that it came with and created a new EXT partition and I think I just checked the  option for "encrypt volume".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Launch `Password and Encryption Keys` from the Unity dash. Try to find the stored password matching your USB drive, right click and delete it.

Comment: Thanks man, that did the trick!  I see a bunch of cached passwords for SMB shares that I removed too :P